Generating AR models using multiple 2D images of the same object
I am trying to make a project in which i can develope a 3D AR model using multiple 2D images
Is there any library which i can use for this task?
I tried few APIs but the output is not that great.
I am trying to make a app that converts 2D images of specs into a 3D model.
I want to input multiple images to the model and the output should be an .obj AR file.

Welcome new user. (1) tap edit and tell us what system or platform you are using. Is this unity3D or ?  (2)  That is cutting edge technology that doesn't work very well - really your only hope is to try the various services available. Most are paid.

I was hoping to try making 3d models with Nerf and train it to output a .obj file for spectacles, will this approach help me get a really good 3d model?

Have you tried instant Nerf from nVidia ?  Please just google "Nerf software .." and try some !

try googling .. https://polymuse.tech
